# How to check when was last time the User logged in?

Tags: python, django

I would like to update my model if the user did not logged in the day before .

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=user_logged_in)
    def user_logged_in_streak(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

        today: date = timezone.now().date()
        class_completed = ClassAttempt.objects.filter(user=instance.user,
                                                      status='completed',)\
            .order_by('-updated_at')\
            .first()

        if (instance.user.last_login == today - timedelta(days=2) and (class_completed.updated_at == today - timedelta(days=2))):
            UserStatisticStatus.objects.update(day_streak=0)
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution, instance will no work, pass request as an argument to get the user informations

```
    @receiver(user_logged_in, sender=User)
    def user_logged_in(sender, request, *args, **kwargs):

        last_log = request.user.last_login.date()
        today: date = timezone.now().date()
        class_completed = ClassAttempt.objects.filter(user=request.user,
                                                      status='completed', ) \
            .order_by('-updated_at') \
            .first()

        if (last_log == today - timedelta(days=1) and (
                class_completed.updated_at.updated_at.date() == today - timedelta(days=1))):
            pass
        elif (last_log == today - timedelta(days=1) and (
                class_completed == None)):
            UserStatisticStatus.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(day_streak=0)

        elif (last_log != today) and (last_log != today - timedelta(days=1)):
            UserStatisticStatus.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(day_streak=0)
            
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a condition on the basis of instance.user.last_login and current timestamp - timedelta(1). Use python datetime.

Comment: So I'v just updated the code, will the work ? , not sure about the <sender>, should the be the User model ?

Comment: since you are using signal when user logged in it automatically got triggered.

Comment: ok would this work as it is ?

Comment: Expecting the result

Comment: Does not seem to be working, also hard to debug properly I guess

Comment: Try to put logger in signal or print statement to see the output there in signal.

Comment: any chance you can post it in code, not sure how to do that ?

Comment: when you want to trigger signal?
is it on login?

Comment: Yes on log in I want to trigger the signal and check last log in from that user and then write the logic based on that